# passing html geolocation data to php

Tags: php, html

I am new to html and php(2hours).
I want to save the visitor geolocation data and ip address in a log file.
here is my code, i cannot pass the location data into php.
how can I do it?
I have no idea of what am i doning now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Dont click it</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It Anyway</button>

<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    {enableHighAccuracy:true}
         }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
    localStorage.loc= "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    x.innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("loc");
    locOfSluts=localStorage.getItem("loc");

  }

</script>
<?php

    $$locofsluts = $_POST["locOfSluts"];
    $contfile = fopen("NumOfSluts.log", "r");
    $cont = fread($contfile,filesize("NumOfSluts.log"));
    fclose($contfile );
    $cont = $cont+1;
    $contfile = fopen("NumOfSluts.log", "w");
    fwrite($contfile , $cont);
    fclose($contfile );

    $log = fopen("log.log", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $ipOfSluts = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]."\n";
    fwrite($log, date("Y-m-d-h:i:s")."\n");
    fwrite($log, $ipOfSluts);
    fwrite($log, $locofsluts);
    fclose($log);

    ?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well first of all you are pushing variables ($ipOfSluts) to the file that are not declared.

Comment: it should be $ipOfvis

Answer (score 1):

Since PHP is executed on the server and JavaScript is executed on the client side in your browser you cannot simply pass information from JavaScript to PHP.

The only way to archive that is to create an extra PHP script that saves the information given by some parameters and use AJAX to open an new request to this PHP file.

**The problem more in detail:**

You declare `$loc` in JavaScript and use it in PHP. It's generally not possible to use variables across multiple programming languages!!!

In this case please make sure you know the differences between PHP and JavaScript:

If you make a request to a file at the web server the PHP script starts running and generates the HTML response (so everything between  is evaluated) and the output of all this will be sent to the client. Usually the connection to the server is closed afterwards.

So the PHP part of your script already ran at the server and is NOT served to the client (who wouldn't be able to run your PHP anyway since it cannot write on files at the server for example). Now your browser starts parsing the HTML result and builds the webpage for you. When the document is ready the web engine of your browser executes JavaScript and it collects the GEO information.

So when having this in mind you will see that your code cannot work for many different reasons.

**The solution in detail:**

You need to make an asynchronous solution for this. So you should have a .php file on your server that has no specific output. The only thing it does is saving the information given via GET parameters to your log file.

Now on your website you need a JavaScript code that fetches the GEO location data and when it succeed it should open an new connection to your .php file and pass the information you want to save as parameters to the .php script. With jQuery this would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'save.php?lang='+lang+'&lat='+lat,
}).done(function() {
   alert('Information saved');
})
```

Comment: I dont understandm, where should I put the $.ajax code and what it does? save the html geo data into a url? then how the server is going to respond this? the $.ajax should run on client side? how am i going to deploy iquery for every client?

Comment: $.ajax() is jQuery (JavaScript) so it should run on the browser. It opens (after the page and everything is loaded) a new request to a new file in the background and loads its result. But in this case we are not interested in the output but in passing data to this script. Check  the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - you should use it when you successfully loaded the Geolocation data. And the PHP part should be in a separated file that is executed by AJAX and not when the page is loaded since it cannot have any information at this point.

Comment: Your code still contains syntax errors like "$$" and I still can't see any async request. Same problem as above with all your code.